# How to get Bearer token for Event Hub Azure

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have created an Event Hub in Microsoft Azure, I am trying to perform a GET operation to get details of my Event Hub following the docs : - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/get, but I need "Bearer Token" to get the result in POSTMAN, how to get the token? Detail explanation would be appreciated

Comment: You'll need to create an app in Azure AD and acquire a token with those credentials. Also you need to assign enough privileges for that app to access your event hub. I found this with a quick search though the Azure AD part is a bit out of date: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudpfe/2016/09/14/call-azure-resource-manager-rest-apis-from-your-net-application/. You'll find Azure Active Directory in the Portal, no need to go to manage.windowsazure.com, that's the old portal that you can't use anymore.

Comment: It means you do not have a sufficient role in Azure AD to do anything there. You'll need to get an Application Developer role in Azure AD from your administrator or have them make the app.

Comment: Type Web app/API, generate a key and then give you the application id, key + tenant id. Oh yeah homepage URL for the app can just be `https://localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) to create Azure Active Directory application to get the `clientId`,`secret` and `tenantId`.

[image]

Then grant permission of event hub resource to your AD app.

[image]

Then get access token as follows

[image]

Then use it to perform a GET operation to get details.

[image]

Hope it helps you.