# Calling Azure CDN Purge's REST API from Flow returns Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cdn, power-automate

I want to purge an Azure CDN endpoint from Microsoft Flow. The CDN Profile's Pricing Ties is `Standard Verzion`.

I have created a Microsoft Flow with an `HTTP - HTTP` action.

I used an URL generated by the tool shown by clicking on `Try it` on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/endpoints/purgecontent and filling the necessary fields.

I want to purge all CDN content so I put the following as a body (I hope this is the right way as the official docs were silent about this use case).

```
{
  "contentPaths": [
    "/*"      
  ]
}
```

I have created a `Registered application` in the `Azure Active Directory` and used that to fill in `Active Directory OAuth` fields of the `HTTP - HTTP` action. I presume that the OAuth authentication is succeeding as if I put wrong values in any of the fields I get a respective error message.

So the `HTTP - HTTP` action is filled as on the following image. The image mostly shows where I got the values I used on the real flow.

[image]

When I run the flow it fails and shows just `Unauthorized.` inside the failed `HTTP - HTTP` action.
[image: HTTP box with Unauthorized written inside.]

I have tried to add the app as a `Contributor` role of the `CDN Profile` but the error stayed the same.

How to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems that you missed the access token in the request.

If you want to generate the token for your azure ad app(service principal), you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) and the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491350/how-to-get-bearer-token-for-event-hub-azure) of generating the access token via postman.

Also, you could try to add the app as a role in the logic app.

Comment: As the HTTP action has fields for OAuth, I expect it is capable to first authenticate and than call the actual url. I've added a screenshot to the question showing the HTTP action definition.

Comment: May be you mean [Validating bearer JWT access tokens](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/validating-jwt-access-tokens)? I think you are unnecessary to do so, if the token is invalid, it will give the error.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Flow (a Microsoft's IFTTT-like service). There is no code-programming from the user point of view.

Comment: It started to work when I changed Audience to https://management.azure.com.